# change font size on line breaks that start with array values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update font size on only specific lines that start with what's in my `Array`. I tried adding in a `*` wildcard, but it won't work because I have my `""s`.

How can I have this code loop through to find `(i)` and then change font size for `i` and the whole line after `i`?

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant, i As Long
    A = Array("Table:", "Source:", "Description:", "Available Selections:", "Sample Data:", "Used in Fields:", _
                "Other Referenced Fields:", "Workbooks Used In:", "Dashboards Used In:", "Sheets Used In:", _
                    "Default Format Type:", "Default Sort:", "Default Color:", "Default Font:", "Default Font Size:")
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
           .Replacement.Font.Size = 10
           .Execute FindText:=A(i), ReplaceWith:=A(i), Format:=True, _
             Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

example of how it needs to look [image]

I don't want it to touch the top word because I want that text to remain slightly larger, so I designated the lines I'd like it to affect based on the first word and : for each line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    A = Array("Table:", "Source:", "Description:", "Available Selections:", "Sample Data:", "Used in Fields:", _
                "Other Referenced Fields:", "Workbooks Used In:", "Dashboards Used In:", "Sheets Used In:", _
                    "Default Format Type:", "Default Sort:", "Default Color:", "Default Font:", "Default Font Size:")
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
        With Selection.Find
           .Replacement.Font.Size = 10
           .Execute FindText:=A(i) & "*^013", ReplaceWith:="^&", Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Changes to your code: set `Selection.Find.MatchWildcards` to `True` and tweaked your search and replace terms. NB: I assumed the entire paragraph starting with the terms in the array needs to change format